# Path sequences and isomorphism of graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. For each $v\in V$ we define the *path sequence* $\text{ps}^G_v: \omega\to \omega$ where $\text{ps}_v(n)$ is the number of vertices that can be reached from $v$ via a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) of length at most $n$. (So $\text{ps}^G_v(0) = 1$ for all $v\in V$.) Of course, these path sequences are eventually constant.

What is an example of pairwise non-isomorphic graphs $G_i = (V_i, E_i)$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$ such that there is a bijection $\varphi:V_i \to V_2$ and $$\text{ps}^{G_1}_v = \text{ps}^{G_2}_{\varphi(v)}$$ for all $v\in V$?

Comment: This might be an interesting question if you restricted it to some special class of graphs—trees, maybe? I haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take two nonisomorphic $k$-regular graphs of order $n$ and diameter $2$. For any vertex $v$ in such a graph, $|\{w:d(v,w)\le r\}|$ is $1$ if $r=0$, $k+1$ if $r=1$, and $n$ if $r\gt1$.

With $k=3$ and $n=6$ you can take $K_{3,3}$ and the [triangular prism graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_graph). They are nonisomorphic because only one of them has a connected complement, and only one of them is planar.